# After receiving alarm notification , page not directed to another activity?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am a newbie in android developement.I have set an alarm at an 5 seconds interval.
So once the alarm is triggered, I have set a notification.But when I select notification,I configured the page to move some other activity .But nothing is happen.

```
 public class Snooze extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent intent1=new Intent(context,NotificaitonPage.class);
        intent1.putExtra("notify","SNOOZE") ;



        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        int requestCode = 0;

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Push notification alerts")
                .setContentText("This for alaram notification")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("This for alaram notification")) ;

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        notificationManager.notify(0, noBuilder.build()); //0 = ID of notification

    }
}
```

So, Please help me to solve the problem.
Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following flag to your `intent1`:

```
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

As pointed out by @Alexander in another answer, you also need to setup your `PendingIntent` as:

```
pendingIntent.getActivity();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create **PendingIntent** you should use `PendingIntent.getActivity()` instead of `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`. See more [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity)